# Why Can't I Subnet the First Octet?

Tags: ipv4, subnet

Why is it possible for me to create a network such as 10.0.0.0/9 which ranges from 10.0.0.0 to 10.127.255.255 but not a network such as 128.0.0.0/2 which should range from 128.0.0.0 to 191.255.255.255.

For some reason I am unallowed to create subnet masks with a CIDR value of less than 8. Why is this so?

Comment: What  are you using that is not letting you do this? 10.0.0.0/9 and 128.0.0.0/2 are perfectly acceptable prefixes.

Comment: I am using Cisco IOS

Comment: Make sure you have the `ip classless` global command enabled.

Comment: In my lab, I can successfully configure an interface on Cisco IOS to `ip address 128.0.0.1 192.0.0.0` even with `no ip classless` configured.

Comment: In fact, I can form OSPF adjacencies with interfaces in the 128.0.0.0/2 range. :)

Comment: Which IOS version and what are you configuring exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason is history.

Originally the internet was conceived as a network of a small number of large networks. The first octet identified the network and the remaining three identified a host within that network. Later we got network classes to allow a larger number of smaller networks. Later still we got CIDR to allow more efficient allocation of addresses to networks.

Meanwhile as people started using IP directly on top of lan protocols the need for subnetting appeared to break up networks into manageable chunks. Initially with a fixed subnet mask through an organisation and later with variable length subnet masks.

Subnetting was always conceived as a way to break up "network" into managable size chunks, the largest "network" was what we now call a /8, so there would have been no reason to allow a subnet mask shorter than that (which doesn't mean some stuff didn't allow it anyway, some implementations are stricter than others).